# Bio Impedance Calculator circuit

Tags: frequency, impedance, generator

I'm currently in a project which consists of making a bio Impedance meter with the [AD5933](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD5933.pdf). This could be a very easy project if I had to use the frequency range (1Hz->100kHz) that give the onboard frequency generator but no. I have to go as high as 1MHz which the AD5933 won't do.

I thought of a solution, which takes the use of the [AD9833](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD9833.pdf). This component is a programmable waveform generator that makes me able to output the desired sinewave at the frequency I want.
My solution is to completely get rid of the output of the AD5933 and connect the output of the AD9833 to the implant and still use the impedance meter of the AD5933. I can see in the datasheet that to calculate the impedance, the calculations are independent of the frequency. I just have to "sync" the sent frequency to the received result in the board I will use.

From your experience, is something like that possible, or did I forget to take something into account that forces me to use the onboard wave generator from the AD5933?

Thank you in advance for your responses.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the AD5933 block diagram from [the datasheet](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD5933.pdf):
[image]

As far as I can tell, there are 2 problems. First, its analog IOs are buffered with Opamps. Their GBW might not be sufficient to work 10x out of spec. Lastly, there's a LPF block before the ADC which reduces the effective bandwidth of the device.